# Passing value from one void function to another void function in java

Tags: java

I am a student of class X.I am doing a school project in java. I got stuck here somewhere. My Code is as follow.

```
package school.PRo;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    class Telephone_Bill
       {
           String c_name[]=new String[10];
           String c_add[]=new String[10];
           String phno[]=new String[10];
           void accept(int n)
                {
                     Telephone_Bill ob=new Telephone_Bill();
                    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
                      int i;
                     String name[]=new String[10];
                     String add[]=new String[10];
                     String ph[]=new String[10];
                     for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                        {
                            System.out.println("Index Number:>>"+i+1);
                            System.out.print("Enter The name of the customer:>>");
                            name[i]=in.nextLine();
                            c_name[i]=name[i];
                            System.out.print("Enter The address of the customer:>>");
                            add[i]=in.nextLine();
                            c_add[i]=add[i];
                            System.out.print("Enter The phone number of the customer:>>");
                            ph[i]=in.nextLine();
                            phno[i]=ph[i];
                        }
                        ob.show(n);
                    }
                    static void main(String args[])
                        {
                            int n;
                            Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
                            Telephone_Bill ob=new Telephone_Bill();
                            System.out.print("Enter the no. of customer:>");
                            n=in.nextInt();
                            ob.accept(n);
                        }
                    void show()
                        {
                            int i=0,p;
                            while(i<p)
                                {
                                    System.out.print(c_name[i]+" "+c_add[i]+" "+phno[i]);
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

What I am facing problem is that when I am passing the value from **function void accept()** to **function void show()** I cannot pass that value from one void function to another void function. Something I am going wrong. So, I want to know how can I pass the value from one void function to another void function. 
Please help me to get rid from here.
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: please, provide an error

Comment: I learned to decipher these kinds of posts back on the Sun Java Forums... :)

Comment: when you pass an argument to another function, the other function declaration should have an argument which can actually accept it. You are missing it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you pass an argument to a function, that function declaration should have an argument which can actually accept it. You are missing it here

```
void show() {
}
```

When you change you method show to

```
void show(int arg)
```

now your method **show** can receive and argument in the variable **arg**

void states that, the method **show** doesn't return anything. It doesn't have anything to do with what argument is passed.

Read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) for more info

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a parameter to the show() method.

```
void show(int p) {
```